# CodeEffects LoadSettings() not updating with new data without a hard reload (Angular)

Tags: rule-engine, business-rules, codeeffects

Currently have an Angular implementation of CE being initialized and loadSettings being applied OnInit. When the component is destroyed and reloaded, I can see that the new data is correct for loadSettings(), but CE continues to display the original dataset. The only time it updates correctly is with a hard reload, which is not a solution for a SPA.

Is it not possible to update the settings of a CE instance without a hard reload?

Rough example:

```
ngOnInit() {
this.ce = $rule.init(settings.editorData);
this.ce.loadSettings(data.sourceData);
}

ngOnDestroy() {
this.ce.dispose();
this.ce.clear();
}
```

When one of the items gets updated, and the page with CE on it is viewed again, (different component) I see the sourceData is updated with the correct data we want to display, but CE shows the original data set still....

Any ideas?

Comment: This issue will be corrected in the next minor version of Code Effects editor due out in a couple of weeks